# Passing a tikzcd as an argument of a theorem style environment

Tags: amsthm, tikz-cd

I would like to pass a tikz-cd environment as an argument of a theorem (between `[]`). Unfortunately, in the below code, the tikz-cd environment is shown partially. Is there a way to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
[\begin{tikzcd}%
        X \arrow{r}{\psi} & Y \arrow{r}{\pi} &Z
    \end{tikzcd}]
Content of theorem
\end{thm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd simply use `\begin{thm}[$X\xrightarrow{\psi}Y\xrightarrow{\pi}Z$]`; the arrows are shorter, but it's how they should be.

Comment: Many thanks, in fact I prefer short arrows like what you have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to  `&` being an active character. A work-around consists in replacing it with a command.  Note that we'll have to compensate for the padding of the `tikz-cd` environment.

Using `tikz-cd` is not necessary for the diagram you want to type: simple `\xrightarrow`s will do. However, you might need to draw more complex diagrams that would require some dedicated package, so I give both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[$ X \xrightarrow{\makebox[2em]{$\scriptstyle\psi$}} Y \xrightarrow{\makebox[2em]{$\scriptstyle\pi$}} Z $]
  Content of theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[\tikzset{ampersand replacement=\&}%
    \begin{tikzcd}%
      \mkern -8mu X \arrow{r}{\psi} \& Y \arrow{r}{\pi} \& Z\mkern -8mu
    \end{tikzcd}]
  Content of theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing both solutions (I liked your solution without tikz-cd).

Comment: @egreg: Thanks again for correcting the code!