# Define macro for tikz-cd environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-cd

I'd like to have a shorthand for

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    % ..diagram code...
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

I tried with

```
\tikzset{ampersand replacement=\&}
\def\bcd#1\ecd{\begin{center}\begin{tikzcd}#1\end{tikzcd}\end{center}}
```

Where the first command [should fix problems with ampersands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380867/passing-a-tikzcd-as-an-argument-of-a-theorem-style-environment). Without it, I get errors about them but even with it, `pdflatex` doesn't seem to be able to produce a right output (I get the error `Package tikz: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/cache/main-figure1"  "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'figures/cache/main-figure1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:)...`)

The error seems to occur on regular images, so maybe it's a problem of interoperability with the `\tikzset` command? If I disable `tikz-external`, the only error remaining is `Float(s) lost`.

Comment: Are you adding captions to those diagrams? If not, the `figure` environment is rather pointless. I'd remove it and `\centering`, and use a `center` environment instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error was caused by another, unrelated, tikz environment used in the wrong place.

So actually the shorthand in the question works.

Comment: making such shorthands is usually in the end not a good idea, it makes it much harder for your editor to offer context sensitive syntax highlighting or help and given reasonable editor setup it does not save any typing as you should be able to add `\begin{..} \end{...}` in just a few keystrokes.

Comment: It's a matter of consistency. If I want to change how to display my diagrams (or equations, figures, ...), I just need to edit in one place. Basic programming wisdom (DRY). Losing some syntac highlighting is often an acceptable trade off. That said, this is my experience, YMMV.